# How to customise the iOS badge number background

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem, badge

How can I customise the badge number on UITabBarItem?

Something like this

[image]

Comment: I guess you have to implement your won UIView subclass create your own badgeView

Comment: Let say I have created one. How can I add on to the UITabBarItem? Because we cannot just subview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a Look at [MKNumberBadgeView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mknumberbadgeview). Its a little Class for your Custom BadgeView.

Using it like this I am able to add it to my custom UITabBarController:

```
    MKNumberBadgeView *badge = [[MKNumberBadgeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, self.view.frame.size.height-20, 30, 30)];
    badge.value = 12;
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
    [[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:badge];
```

Wich will look like this:

[image]

Of course you have to take care of rotating issues when adding the badgeView to the window.
But I guess you can customize MKNumberBadgeView to make it look the way you want it, give it a try.